# remove .php extension with .htaccess for subdomains?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm not expert at url-rewrites.

My domain is `helloboy`.

My subdomains are `www` and `labs`.

I would like to remove **.php extension** only for the **subdomain** `labs` **and** the directory `graph`?

From: http://labs.helloboy.com/graph/load/show.php

To: http://labs.helloboy.com/graph/load/show/

How can I do that?

**Here is my code for `.htaccess`:**

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^labs\.helloboy\.com$ /$1.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(graph/load/.*?)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Do the sub-domains map to a directory?

Comment: @BenM yes ! `labs` maps to `/www/labs`. Eg :  `labs.helloboy.com/graph/` maps to `/www/labs/graph/`

Comment: So I guess you want to do two things: redirect the files (existing or also non-existing?) with the .php extension under graphs/load and remove the extension (will look like a folder?) AND rewrite that URL to the .php equivalent? Well that would cause an endless loop, but it should be simple if you're just doing the rewriting bit.

Comment: @kjetilh Yeah, that's what I want. But I'm not expert at url-rewrites... :(

Comment: As I said doing both actions would create an endless loop. `show.php` would redirect to `show/` then show would rewrite to `show.php` which would redirect to `show/` again etc. If you can change your URLs to go to *http://labs.helloboy.com/graph/load/show/* then one can rewrite it to *http://labs.helloboy.com/graph/load/show.php*. OR you can rename the .php files to for example *internal-show.php* then if the user visits `show.php` you'd redirect to `show/` and rewrite to the internal file. Apologies if it's my explanation seems complicated :).

Comment: @kjetilh Yeah, it seems complicated :p. What do your purpose for `htaccess code` ?

Comment: @Steffi I'll add it as an answer, it's kind of long :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  labs.helloboy.com$ 
RewriteRule ^graph/(.*)/?$ graph/$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: He needs it for the **subdomain** *labs* and the **directory** *graph*

Comment: I can't make it work... I'm wondering if this is not because of `labs` is in the `/www` directory ?

Answer (score 1):

I propose you create a file under graph (or literally anywhere, it's up to you), for example `graph/index.php` that will handle the graph rewrite requests. You would then move `show.php` (and other files you want to redirect) to a different folder appropriate for processing stuff, for example under `graph/lib`.

Now imagine that everything following http://labs.helloboy.com/graph/ is "non-existant", you just handle the requests based on the paths (like *http://labs.helloboy.com/graph/load/show*).

The fictive filestructure is something like this:

```
root (in your case it would prolly be www/labs)
-- .htaccess
-- graph
   -- index.php (handles rewrites, can be anywhere you want but it must be reflected in the .htacces file)
   -- lib (location to store the existing files, can be anywhere you want)
      -- show.php
      -- delete.php
      -- ..etc
```

First of all let's add the rules in .htaccess that will handle the requests and also do the .php redirection:

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# Make sure index.php requests are NOT rewritten, otherwise we'll end up in an endless loop.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^labs\.helloboy\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^graph/index\.php$
RewriteRule .* - [L,NC,QSA]

# Redirect all .php files and remove the extension
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^labs\.helloboy\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(graph/.+)\.php$ $1 [R,NC,QSA]

# Make sure that we won't match existing files or directories, otherwise the lib files will fail. Get the path after "graph/" and add it as a path argument to "graph/index.php".
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^labs\.helloboy\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^graph/(.*) graph/index.php?path=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

We would then need to process the path argument sent to our handler so we can do something useful with it. Note the DEBUG comments, the calls beneath them creates output which I will show later.

### graph/index.php

```
<?php

// NOTE: Consider returning a 404 status code with the header and possibly a redirect if you can't process the paths sanely.

//======
// DEBUG
//======

?><pre><?php var_export( $_GET ) ?></pre><?php

$path = isset( $_GET['path'] ) ? $_GET['path'] : '';

if ( $path ) {
    // Split the path into parts. For example load/show/ becomes an array with two elements: ['load', 'show']
    $paths = array_filter( explode( '/', $path ) );

    //======
    // DEBUG
    //======


    ?><pre><?php var_export( $paths ) ?></pre><?php

    $len = count( $paths );

    if ( $paths ) {
            // If we have any path we attempt to process it

        if ( $paths[0] === 'load' ) {

            // Do something if load

            if ( $len > 1 ) {
                $action = $paths[1];

                switch ( $action ) {
                    case 'show':
                        $file = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "$action.php";

                        //======
                        // DEBUG
                        //======

                        var_dump( $file ) ;

                        if ( file_exists( $file ) ) 
                            require_once $file;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

For the path http://labs.helloboy.com/graph/load/show/ the script would output the following:

```
// This is the contents of the supervariabel $_GET
array (
  'path' => 'load/show/',
)

// This is the path parts after splitting and filtering of the path argument
array (
  0 => 'load',
  1 => 'show',
)

// Here we illustrate that we can include/process any file we wish based on the path contents
string '/your/server/path/graph/lib/show.php' (length=xx)
```

Please let me know if you need further simplification to understand this suggestive solution.